# Can we use printf function in a another user defined function which returns integer datatype?

Tags: c, stack, printf

I creating a code for STACK and I found weather printf() function can be used in a function which can return integer datatype, My function's code is given below,

```
int pop(struct stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->top == -1)
    {
        printf("stack is empty! you can't perform POP operation.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int tmp = stack->data[stack->top];
        stack->top--;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

If my stack is empty it is printing that printf function without any errors or warnings. But that function's return type is integer only so shouldn't it return a value only and should throw error that we can't use printf function?

Comment: " so shouldn't it return a value only and should throw error"  --> There is no _should_, just undefined behavior for the caller to use the return value.  The `printf()` has nothing to do with this, just the lack of a return value.  If you want to exit the program, call `exit()`.

Comment: You can always call `printf`.  It has nothing to do with the return type of the function.  What it *should* do to avoid undefined behavior is return some integer value *after* calling `printf`, such as `return -1` or whatever makes sense.  Or it could call `exit(1);` to exit the program.  What it should not do is implicitly return a garbage value, as the posted code does.